# cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double' for char to numeric conversion in a data frame

Tags: r, transform, numeric

Could anyone explain coerce type 'closure' .

```
> dat
    Zip CuCurrent PaCurrent PoCurrent      Contact Ext          Fax email Status
1 74136         0         1         0 918-491-6998   0 918-491-6659            1
2 30329         1         0         0 404-321-5711                             1
3 74136         1         0         0 918-523-2516   0 918-523-2522            1
4 80203         0         1         0 303-864-1919   0                         1
5 80120         1         0         0 345-098-8890 456                         1

> dat<-transform(dat,zip<-as.numeric(zip))
Error in as.numeric(zip) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
```

I am not able to convert my dataset to numeric.

Comment: Maybe you just meant `Zip` instead of `zip`?

Comment: "closure" essentially means "function". Since you misstyped `Zip` R tries to convert the function `zip` to a numeric, which doesn't work. And of course you shouldn't use `<-` inside `transform`. Use `=` or use `within` instead of `transform`.

Comment: Thanks a lot this solves a problem. Thanks again.